# Survey weights and boostrap wieghts to get counts and CI's

Tags: r, statistics, survey

I have a file containing survey data. For example, the file looks like this:

```
   IDNUMBER   AGE    SEX   NumPrescr   OnPrescr SURV_WGT  BSW1 BSW2....BSW500

   123456      22     1      6           1          ...    ... ...        ...
```

Here, OnPrescrp is a binary variable indicating whether or not the subjects is on prescription meds and BSW1 - BSW500 are the bootstrap weights and SURV_WGT is the survery weight per subject. There are roughly 20000 entries.

I am tasked with creating tables of various statistics within certain age-gender group breakdowns. For example, how many males from 17 to 24 are on prescription medications. And I need a count N and 95% CI for each of these types of calculations. I'm not familiar at all with survey methods.

From what I understand, I can't just simply add the number of people in each category to get the final count N for each question/category (i.e., cannot just add all the males 17 to 24 who are using prescription meds). Instead, I have to take into account the survery weights and bootstrap weights when constructing my final count N and confidence intervals.

I was then told in STATA this is a one line command:

```
    svyset [pw=SURV_WGT], brr(bsw1-bsw500)
```

I am working in R however. What is the equivalent command in R and what exactly is the above command doing?

PS: My sample of roughly 20000 indiviudals is a sample of a population of roughly 35 million.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use the `survey` package in R. This will be your best friend for weighted/complex survey analysis in R.

`install.packages("survey")`

The `survey` package has two main steps to your analysis. The first is creating the `svydesign` object, which stores information about your survey design including weights, replicate weights, data, etc. Then use any number of analysis functions to run analysis/descriptives on those design objects (e.g., `svymean`, `svyby` - for subgroup analysis, `svyglm`, and many more).

Based on your question, you have survey weights and replicate weights (bootstrapped). While the more common `svydesign` function is used for surveys with a single set of weights, you want to use `svrepdesign`, which will allow you to specify survey weights and replicate weights. Check out the documentation, but here is what you can do:

```
mydesign <- svrepdesign(data = mydata,
                        weights = ~SURV_WGT,
                        repweights = "BSW[0-9]+",
                        type = "bootstrap",
                        combined.weights = TRUE)
```

You should read the documentation, but briefly: `data` will be your data frame, `weights` takes your single survey weight vector, usually as a formula, `repweights` is great in that it accepts a regex string that identifies all the replicate weight columns in your data by column name, `type` tells the design what your replicate weights are (how they were derived), `combined.weights` is logical for whether the replicate weights contain sampling weights - I assume this is true but it may not be.

From this design object, you can then run analysis. E.g., let's calculate the average number of prescriptions by sex:

```
myresult <- svyby(~NumPrescr, # variable to pass to function
                  by = ~SEX,  # grouping
                  design = mydesign, # design object
                  vartype = "ci", # report variation as confidence interval
                  FUN = svymean # specify function from survey package, mean here
                  )
```

Hope this helps!

EDIT: if you want to look at something by age groups, as you suggest, you need to create a character or factor variable that is coded for each age group and use that new variable in your `svyby` call.

Comment: Just one quick question. What happens if the counts are too low? Will an error be created? For example lets say our age-sex group is 17-24 year old males. The count of these males (and 95%CI) using med3 might be close to 0. Will the above use of the survey package produce an error in such cases or just input NA?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Even if there is only one observation in the group, it will produce a mean and CIs (if there is one observation these will all be the same number). The weight in this case will not matter as that is the only observation. Once you have more than one observation the weights will play a role in which observations influence the statistic (in this case mean) more or less within that group. If you want to know what the weighted Ns are, use `svytable`.

Comment: I think I understand now! Just one last quick question. I want to also calculate the median, IQR, and range for the various age-sex groups. Would the correct code be to replace NumPrescr by AGE and using age_sex_group for the "by" part and then changing svymean in "FUN"? If so, are there survey functions in package survey that calculate the median, interquartile range and range? Thanks so much!